# Append text in JTextArea does not work

Tags: java, swing, rmi

I'm new to JAVA and for my university project, I have to code a RMI application.

I've coded a server class, a client class and a JFrame class.

The connection between server and clients is working and with an interface I can communicate between them.

To visualize the client (which is now a child of the JFrame class) I've coded the JFrame class mentionend above.
In this JFrame class, I instantiate the client.

Now, let's finally come to my problem:

I call a method A in the server class, that calls an method B in the client and this method B should call a method C in the JFrame class. Specificly, I want to append a String in a JTextArea in the JFrame class, but this does not work. Here's the code. Many thanks in advance.

Server Code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.rmi.AccessException;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author Sebbo
 */
public class ServerImpl implements IServer, Serializable {
    public static ArrayList<IClient> spielerliste = new ArrayList();
    public static ArrayList<IClient> readyListe = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList benutzernamen = new ArrayList();
    private ServerFenster serverfenster;
    private int anzahlKarten = 7;
    ArrayList<Card> kartendeck;
    /*
    public ServerImpl(ServerFenster serverFenster) {
        this.serverfenster = serverFenster;
    }
    */

    public ServerImpl() {

    }

    @Override
    public void clientAnmelden(String benutzername, String clientIndex) throws NotBoundException, RemoteException, AccessException{

        System.out.println(benutzername + " beim Spiel angemeldet!");
        benutzernamen.add(benutzername);
        for (int i = 0; i < benutzernamen.size(); i++ ) {
            System.out.println(benutzernamen.get(i).toString());
        }

        //Find Client
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
        IClient tmpClient = (IClient) registry.lookup( clientIndex );

        spielerliste.add(tmpClient);
        //serverfenster.jPanelHinzufuegen(benutzername);
    } 

    @Override
    public void spielStarten(ArrayList<IClient> readyliste) throws RemoteException {
        kartendeck = Card.kartendeckErzeugen();
        this.kartenAnSpielerVerteilen(readyliste);
    }

    @Override
    public void spielerlisteAnzahlAusgeben() throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println(this.spielerliste.size());
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<IClient> spielerlisteAusgeben() throws RemoteException {
        return this.spielerliste;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param IClient
     */
    public void kartenAnSpielerVerteilen(ArrayList<IClient> readyliste) throws RemoteException {
        for (int i = 0; i < readyliste.size(); i++) {
            readyliste.get(i).handNehmen(kartendeck, anzahlKarten);
            readyliste.get(i).handAusgeben();
            System.out.println("Hand ausgeteilt.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void readyListeChecken() throws RemoteException {
        // spielerliste durchgehen und Spieler, die bereit sind, in ReadyListe verschieben
        for (int i = 0; i < spielerliste.size(); i++) {
            if (spielerliste.get(i).getSpielerstatus()) {
                IClient tmpClient = spielerliste.get(i);
                spielerliste.remove(spielerliste.get(i));
                readyListe.add(tmpClient);
            }
        }

        int anzahlBereiterSpieler = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < readyListe.size(); i++) {
            if (readyListe.get(i).getSpielerstatus()) {
                anzahlBereiterSpieler++;
            }
        }

        if (anzahlBereiterSpieler < 2) {
            System.out.println("Anzahl bereiter Spieler: " + anzahlBereiterSpieler);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Anzahl bereiter Spieler: " + anzahlBereiterSpieler);
            System.out.println("Spiel wird gestartet.");
            spielStarten(this.readyListe);
        }

        anzahlBereiterSpieler = 0;
    }

    public void broadcastMessage(String message) throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println(message);
        for(int i =0; i<spielerliste.size(); i++) {
            spielerliste.get(i).nachrichtEmpfangen(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author Sebbo
 */
public class ClientImpl extends ClientFenster implements IClient, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //private ArrayList<Card> cards;
    private IServer server;
    private IClient client;
    private String benutzername;
    private ArrayList<Card> hand;
    private boolean spielerBereit = true;
    private boolean spielerAmZug = false;

    private static int clientIndex = 0;
    public ClientImpl(IServer server, String benutzername) throws Exception{
                this.hand = new ArrayList();
        this.benutzername = benutzername;
                this.server = server;
                this.server.clientAnmelden(this.benutzername, registerClient());
    }       

        @Override
        public void handNehmen(ArrayList<Card> kartendeck, int anzahlKarten) {
            for (int i = 0; i < anzahlKarten; i++) {
                this.hand.add(kartendeck.get(0));
                kartendeck.remove(kartendeck.get(0));
            }
        }

        int playerIndex;
        private String registerClient() throws RemoteException{

            //Search in all registry keys
            //last clientXX +1

            String key = "Client" + clientIndex++;
            client = (IClient) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject( this, 0 );
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            int index = 0;

            registry.rebind(key, client );



            return key;
        }

        private int getNumberOfPlayers(){
            String keyNumOfPlayers = "playerIndex";
            //Registry=> playerIndex:int

            return -1;
        }
        private void setNumberOfPlayers(){
           //Registry <= playerIndex:int 
        }
        @Override
        public void handAusgeben() throws RemoteException{
            for (Card karte : hand) {
                System.out.println(karte.getFarbe() + " - " + karte.getWert() + " - " + karte.getID());
            }
        }

    @Override
        public String getBenutzername() throws RemoteException{
            return this.benutzername;
        }

    @Override
        public boolean getSpielerstatus() throws RemoteException{
            return this.spielerBereit;
        }

    @Override
        public void bereitMelden() throws RemoteException{
            this.spielerBereit = true;
            this.server.readyListeChecken();
        }

    @Override
        public boolean getSpielerAmZug() throws RemoteException{
            return this.spielerAmZug;
        }

    @Override
    public void setSpielerAmZugTrue() throws RemoteException {
        this.spielerAmZug = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSpielerAmZugFalse() throws RemoteException {
        this.spielerAmZug = false;
    }

    /*
    Methode, die wartet, vom Server ausgelöst zu werden und dann eine Nachricht übermittelt und zurückgibt.
    */

    /**
     *
     * @param message
     * @throws RemoteException
     */


    public void nachrichtEmpfangen(String message) throws RemoteException {
        // Code
        nachrichtInTextAreaEinfuegen(message);
    }

    public IServer getServer() {
        return this.server;
    }
}
```

JFrame code:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Sebbo
 */
public class ClientFenster extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private static IClient client;
    static int playerIndex = 0;
    private static ClientImpl clientImpl;
    private ClientFenster fenster = this;
    /**
     * Creates new form ClientFenster
    */

    public JTextArea getJTextArea2() {
        return jTextArea2;
    }

    public ClientFenster() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Hand ausgeben");

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jTextArea1.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                jTextArea1KeyReleased(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jTextArea2.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea2.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea2);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 267, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(178, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 232, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextArea1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
        if (evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
            Date d1 = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss ");
            String formattedDate = df.format(d1);
            try {
                clientImpl.getServer().broadcastMessage("[" + formattedDate + "] " + clientImpl.getBenutzername() +": " +  jTextArea1.getText());
            } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ClientFenster.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            jTextArea1.setText(null);
        }
    }                                      

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException, Exception {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ClientFenster.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ClientFenster.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ClientFenster.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ClientFenster.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ClientFenster().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
    IServer server = (IServer) registry.lookup( "Server" );


    String benutzername = "Tim";
    clientImpl = new ClientImpl(server, benutzername);
  }

    /*public Client() {
        this.client = (IClient) new Client();
    }*/


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea2;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    /**
     *
     * @param message
     */
    public void nachrichtInTextAreaEinfuegen(String message) {
        jTextArea2.append(message);
        jTextArea2.revalidate();
        jTextArea2.repaint();
    }
}
```

Many, many thanks in advance and sorry for my bad code and english ;-)

Comment: Can you give us more details about what particularly is not working in your B to C communication? Have you tried using a debugger with it?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried the debugger. It is now working without an error, but the string does not become appended to the JTextArea.

Comment: I  call the broadcastMessage method in server, this calls the nachrichtEmpfangen method in client and this calls the nachrichtInTextArea method in JFrame class.

And it seems, like this does not have any effect, because the jtextarea does not show any change.

Comment: This could just be a size / layout issue. What happens if you start jtextarea2 with some initial text? Do that show? What if you then delete the initial text and receive a message?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Thanks to everyone already. If I start it with an initial text the text appears as it should but still nothing changes when I call the methods.

@AndrewThompson thanks, I will be aware of that in future and try to post it like u said

Comment: Another information:

when I debug, at the end, netbeans show me this warning:

Variable information not available, source compiled without -g option

Comment: Where is the server class? Why does `ClientImpl` implement `Serializable`? Do you realize that your server is actually an RMI client, and *vice versa*?

Comment: ServerImpl is the server class. I create an instance in the class ServerFenster. I didn't add it cuz i thought it is too much unneccesary info.

So, I will add the 2 Interfaces and the class ServerFenster, in which I bind the Server object.

Yes, I think I realized that. And I implemented Serializable because I thought it avoids problems within the communication, because you can serialize the serverimpl and deserialize it in other classes.

Thanks and sorry ^^

Comment: Exported remote objects don't have to be Serializable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. Everything was working, but the JTextArea was not scrolling automatically, so the code appended the string above the first line and it was not visible.

A friend fixed it with inserting:

```
jTextArea2.setCaretPosition(jTextArea2.getText().length() - 1);
```

Thanks for your help and I will try to post in a better way in future. Sorry.